# Is it possible to run applications installed on my Hyper-V Win11 inside of my host Win11?

Tags: virtual-machine, remote-desktop, windows-11

A few years back I had an older Macbook and I installed Parallels Desktop on it, and one of the options for Parallels was to run windows applications within OS X, rather than having to boot into windows itself.

I have some work-related applications I need to install on my windows 11 desktop, however I want to keep my work/personal segregated, so I created a virtual machine using Hyper-V and installed that software on another instance of windows 11. I can RDP into the virtual machine and then run the application, but I'd rather have a way to run it from my host operating system. Is this possible?

Comment: As far as I know all what Parallels does is hiding the boot process and the desktop so that it looks like the awindows app is running on MacOS, but effectively you just only see the part of Windows that shows the application. On other VM systems this is called seamless mode. And the icon to start the app is nice convenience function.

Comment: @Robert is correct, all this is doing is making it look like there is no "back wall" to the windows VM, and you can see through it to the underlying Mac desktop. I do the same thing in Windows (host) with virtualbox running linux in "seamless mode" allowing the windows from both OSes to be displayed together.  the window is still running within its native OS however.  Linux can take a different approach, using X-server to display apps running on a different network connected system without using a VM hypervisor.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, unless the application in question is portable,
meaning that it works without installation and without using the registry.

A portable application is usually entirely contained within one folder,
so it is enough to put it inside a shared folder that is shared between
the host and the guest.

In all other cases this is impossible. The segregation between the host
and the guest is an important criteria for securing the host against
the guest, and vice verso.

Comment: I think the question is only how to create an icon on the host system that starts the VM and the app on the guest system in a way that it looks like the app would run locally.